# cocos2dx v3 sprite sheet animation

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

HI i am usimg cocos2dx v3 . i am trying to create a sprite sheet animation.but i get this error:
`void cocos2d::Vector<T>::pushBack(T) [with T = cocos2d::SpriteFrame*]: Assertion object != nullptr failed`

which obviously means that my vector is not getting initialized i guess. but why is it happening , i have the correct file names in Resources folder

```
auto cache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
Vector<SpriteFrame*> frames = Vector<SpriteFrame*>();

frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("1.png"));
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("2.png"));
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("3.png"));
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("4.png"));
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("5.png"));
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("6.png"));
Animation* anim = cocos2d::Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(frames, 0.1f, 1);

Animate* anim_action = cocos2d::Animate::create(anim);
auto sprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrame(frames.front());
sprite->runAction(RepeatForever::create(anim_action));
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));
this->addChild(sprite, 0);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the `Vector` that isn't getting initialized? AFAIK cocos2d `Vector` requires that elements that get added to it have a valid reference, in which case it would mean that on of the `SpriteFrame*` you are trying to add is not valid (and a `nullptr`)

Comment: @UnholySheep i am not sure its the vector that is causing error . i just thought by looking at the error message that i have mentioned above. and yes i have files with those names in the Resource folder. icant figure out the error. if you can help

Comment: I can't help by just looking at the code, you need to use a debugger and figure out which line exactly is causing the assertion to trigger (and using that knowledge you should be able to figure out a solution)

Comment: @UnholySheep its the first push to the vector that is causing errors. but why files are there with same name

Comment: So what is the return value of the call `cache->getSpriteFrameByName("1.png")`? is it a valid object? If yes, how does the state of the `Vector` look like at that point. Since Cocos2d is open source you should also be able to step into `pushBack` itself and analyze every step up to the assert.

Comment: @UnholySheep i got it this line was missing: `cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("run.plist");`